# don't know how to persist data from large file on iOS

Tags: ios, parsing, core-data, persistence, nscoding

Right now I have an application that contains a csv file with over 45,000 entries.  Everytime I run the application, it parses this file (takes roughly 5 min on iphone) putting all the data into a 2D array.  Obviously there is a way of doing this without having to wait 5 min everytime.  Is there a way to use core data for this?  Or NSCoding?  Or should reformat the file and make it into a swift file that is just an entire array declaration (not sure if this one would save time)?

Comment: Converting it to a core data file and then including the database in your bundle would probably be much more effective. Particularly if you can modify your app so that it can query core data as required rather than loading everything into memory at the start.

Comment: alright thanks ill try and do that!